# How to use jquery plugins in nodejs and ES6 import?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm using  a jquery plugin for calendar http://kylestetz.github.io/CLNDR/ 
Currently I'm using it with CDN
But I want to use it as a nodejs module what is the best way to do it ?

Edit: I'm using babel Transpiler and es6 syntax.

Comment: jQuery is mainly for DOM manipulation, why do you need it in node ? are you parsing HTML ?

Comment: because I'm using babel

Comment: How would using babel force you to need to parse HTML using jQuery?

Comment: @Sagar You don't make sense. Babel does not require jQuery plugins.

Comment: @Bergi But my project needs it. I'm updating my question to make it more clear.

Comment: So you want to use babel (that runs on node.js) to transpile ES6 scripts for the client that happen to include jQuery modules? You don't really want to use jQuery in node.js?

Comment: @Bergi If not in nodejs where should I ?

Comment: @Sagar In a client website? As said by others, jQuery (and its plugins) need the DOM, which is available in browsers not in node.

Comment: @Bergi You are correct. Then how can I make jQuery and its plugins available those in my web page ?

Comment: Just download it and include it via a `<script>` tag. It should be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: @Bergi I want to manage my dependencies with npm

Comment: @Sagar: That particular plugin doesn't appear to be available on npm

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin has not been written as an ES6 module you would need to do this yourself. Since jQuery plugins simply attach themselves to an existing jQuery object they don't really export anything of note. So you can simply wrap the plugin in a immediately invoked function and export that. Remember to either import jQuery in the plugin file or make it available globally.

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';

const calendar = (function ($) {
    ... your jquery plugin code
    ... can live here 
}(jQuery));
```

If you feel inclined to learn from this you could also fork the project and rewrite the plugin code as an ES6 class and make it available on npm for others.

Comment: If I write a jQuery plugin like in your example, should I put `"jquery"` in the `peerDependencies` section of my plugin's `package.json`? This way, if I add to the `jQuery` prototype, I will add to the same jQuery object the consumer of my plugin/library. Or is it enough to use `jquery` as a normal dependency (`dependencies`)?